# SQL Server - where + TVF/SVF, cross-apply, T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, where-clause, cross-apply

I was trying to create a SQL to pull out data based on date, now having troble to use where clause to get what I really need
I have following table and TVF:

```
/* dbo.weeks  -> column(weeknum), column(date)  **date is all Fridays** */
weeknum    date
  1     2001-09-21
  2     2001-09-28
  3     2001-10-05
 ...        ....
/* fnBenchMark(@weeknum)  -> display benchmark data based on weeknum */
```

Here is my code:

```
SELECT  p.weeknum, p.date, q.companyid, q.index 
FROM dbo.Weeks AS p 
cross apply 
dbo.fnBenchmark(p.weeknum) as q 
where date = '2001-09-21'

/* Here is what I wish to add to above code but don't know how to do it */

if    
    date in dbo.Weeks column (date)  --if date on where clause is a Friday and it is on dbo.weeks table 
then run above code    
else 
    change date to LastFridayDate    --if date on where clause is Sat~Thur, then use previous Friday's date
then run above
```

For example, let's say 2001-09-21 is Friday, if I enter **2001-09-24** on the where clause, I want the SQL to run "where date = "**2001-09-21**" since 2001-09-24 I entered is not Friday"

Maybe I should create another function (SVF?) to return the previous Friday's date based on the parameter @date I entered? and then use:

```
where date = fnFridayCheck(@date I entered)
```

Comment: What is `**date**`???

Comment: Adding the types  and or a create table statement could help.

Comment: What if you wrote a function to get the next (or previous - if you choose a wednesday, do you want the last or next Friday?) Friday. So your `WHERE` clause would be something like `WHERE [date] = fnFriday('2001-09-24')`. You would then have to write this as a function that took 1 date input and uses your dbo.weeks table to output the closest date that is also a Friday.

Comment: Also, why are you using ** around some of your fields? This doesn't look like any T-SQL that I've ever seen. Are you trying to bold them a la reddit formatting?

Comment: @Tingo  I guess you are right, maybe I can create a new FridayCheck SVF then use where date = fnFridayCheck(@date I entered)

Answer (score 0):

mayby you could use

```
datepart(dw,getdate())
```

and than just storedprocedure or just a query for example

```
IF datepart(dw,getdate()) = 6
BEGIN
  something if it's a friday (because 6 in dateprart points to firday)
END
ELSE
BEGIN
  something else to do
END
```